# How to get the names of the instances of a class?

Tags: python, class, instance

How do you get the names of instances of a class?
I've tried this...

```
l=[]
l2=[]
l3=[]
l4=[]

class Rolf():
    def __init__ (self):
        l.append(self)
#        l2.append(*self)    # ERROR: TypeError: list.append() argument after * must be an iterable, not Rolf
        l3.append(str(self))
#        l4.append(str(*self)) # ERRORL TypeError: str() argument after * must be an iterable, not Rolf
        
a = Rolf()
b = Rolf()
c = Rolf()

print(f"1) No of instances= {len(l)}")
print(f"2) List of instances= {l}")
print(f"3) instances are of class type {str(l[0].__class__)}")
print(f"4) for list 'l', Name of each instance= {i for i in l}")
# print(f"5) for list 'l2', Name of each instance= {i for i in l2}")
print(f"6) for list 'l3', Name of each instance= {i for i in l3}")
# print(f"7) for list 'l4', Name of each instance= {i for i in l4}")
```

l and l3 are attempts to get the name (a string) of the instance, but still their object location in memory shows.

So what is the correct syntax to put into the constructor so the name of the created instance gets saved as a string into a list?

Output:

```
1) No of instances= 3
2) List of instances= [<__main__.Rolf object at 0x7f8e3beb3fd0>, <__main__.Rolf object at 0x7f8e3beb39a0>, <__main__.Rolf object at 0x7f8e3beb3970>]
3) instances are of class type <class '__main__.Rolf'>
4) for list 'l', Name of each instance= <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8e3be9bca0>
6) for list 'l3', Name of each instance= <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7f8e3be9bca0>
```

Comment: What do you mean "name"? The identifier to which you assign it (if any) is **not** an attribute of the instance.

Comment: If you want to give a name to these instances, pass a string into the init method.

Comment: What I meant by 'name' is (referring to the code) is
'a', 'b' and 'c', the name of the instance.

Comment: @ khelwood.
Aaah... so make an instance which contains it's own name e.g.
a = Rolf('a')
and in the __init__ part:
    def __init__ (self, name):
Yes! That works.. Now
print(f"2) List of instances= {l}") gives ['a', 'b', 'c']
Thank you. That was a lovely solution.

Comment: @Micklos the variable name is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

As @khelwood suggested: If you want to give a name to these instances, pass a string into the init method.

```
class Rolf():
    def __init__ (self, name):
        self.name = name

l = []        
l.append(Rolf("Alice"))
l.append(Rolf("Bob"))
l.append(Rolf("Charles"))
l.append(Rolf("Dany"))

print(f"1) No of instances= {len(l)}")
print(f"2) List of instances= {[i.name for i in l]}")
print(f"3) instances are of class type {[str(i.__class__) for i in l]}")



1) No of instances= 4
2) List of instances= ['Alice', 'Bob', 'Charles', 'Dany']
3) instances are of class type ["<class '__main__.Rolf'>", "<class '__main__.Rolf'>", "<class '__main__.Rolf'>", "<class '__main__.Rolf'>"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Sembei but from my limited understanding I don't see how Alice, Charles etc are instances of class Rolf? In my code the names of the instances I wanted to get into a list were 'a', 'b' and 'c'. Re: your code wouldn't it have to written  Alice = Rolf() for Alice to be an instance? (and isn't it naughty to have an instance starting with a capital letter?)

Comment: But...
Is there a way to pythonicly 'read' the (identifier)'name' of the instance 
in a kind of  "  get_instance_name(self)  " way, instead of hard coding it as a parameter when instantiating? That would be the ideal.

Comment: You can use a dictionary if you want. `my_dict = {"a": "Rolf()", "b": "Rolf()"}`  then you can access the instance named a by doing `my_dict["a"]`. You can then get a list of the instances you have by doing `my_dict.keys()`. The instance however doesn't have a name by itself. It has a unique id though, that you could use as a name if you want.

Comment: Thats interesting. Thanks Sembei. It gives another way of doing it but it still "hard codes" the 'a' instance name. Python must store the 'a' character representing the class (my guess is it's in the memory block for the object) and because when you make or tie a instance attribute/method to 'a' and other instances, python must record the 'a' to allow you to reference it. How to 'grab' that info where 'a' is stored though. ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for the variable names that you assigned instances of Rolf to, you could find them in `globals()` if they are global variables.

```
class Rolf():
    def __init__ (self):
        pass
        
a = Rolf()
b = Rolf()
c = Rolf()
d = [1,2,3] # not a Rolf
    
for name,instance in list(globals().items()):
    if isinstance(instance,Rolf):
        print(name, "is a Rolf")

a is a Rolf
b is a Rolf
c is a Rolf
```

*Note: This is not something you would typically need to do in any real life program.  Unless this question was just out of curiosity, you should revisit the reason why you want to get variable names and perhaps consider using dictionaries*

[EDIT] If your objective is to automatically maintain a list (or dictionary) of all instances, you can add a class variable that you feed in the constructor:

```
class Rolf():
    roster = list()
    def __init__ (self):
        Rolf.roster.append(self)
        ...
        
a = Rolf()
b = Rolf()
c = Rolf()

for r in Rolf.roster:
    print(r)

<__main__.Rolf object at 0x7f7d786542e8>
<__main__.Rolf object at 0x7f7d786544e0>
<__main__.Rolf object at 0x7f7d78698c18>
```

*If you do this however, you have to keep in mind that deletion of instances will need an explicit process.  The list of instances will keep a reference to all instances preventing them from being automatically released when no longer used in the rest of the program.  It may be worth considering using weak references in the list (see the weakref module)*

Comment: Thanks very much Alain.
I wanted the names in a list so I can iterate over all created instances and also to programmatically/iteratively synthesize class/attribute/method calls.

Comment: @ Alain et al.
I wanted the names in a list so I can iterate over all created instances at that time and also to programmatically/iteratively synthesize class/attribute/method calls for automated object creation (different project).
An example of the first objective was to use the list of 'student objects/profiles'  who graduated, so that I can add new attributes to the current instances, e.g:

for name in list, name.qualification="B.Sc."

But name is treated as a string and not an object, so my plan can't be realised... yet.